# Law of total probability proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove $P(A_1\cap A_2\,\cap ...\cap A_n)=P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3|A_1\cap A_2)\,\cap ... \cap\,P(A_n|A_1\cap A_2\,\cap ...\cap A_{n-1})$ assuming that the conditional probabilities exist.

Here is what I have done:

Since $P(A\cap B)=P(B|A)P(A)$,
$$P(A_1\cap A_2\,\cap ...\cap A_n)=P(A_1)P(A_2\,\cap ...\cap A_n|P(A_1))
$$

$$=P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3\cap ...\cap A_n|P(A_1)\cap P(A_2))$$
$$...$$
$$=P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3|A_1\cap A_2)...P(A_n|A_1\cap A_2\,\cap...\cap A_{n-1})
$$

I feel as if I'm just taking for granted that when you have $P(A_2\cap ...\cap A_n|A_1)$, you can break it up into $P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3\cap...\cap |A_1\cap A_2)$. What should I add to the proof, if anything?

Comment: To prove the part you took for granted, use $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}.$$ When you expand $$P(A_2 | A_1)P(A_3 \cap \cdots \cap A_n | A_1 \cap A_2)$$ in this way, you'll see that it equals $P(A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_n | A_1)$.

Comment: I think there are some typos about $P(A_{1})$

Comment: If you wanted a formal proof, you are going to end up using induction and $P(B \cap C \mid D) = \frac{P(B \cap C \cap D)}{P( D)} = \frac{P(B \cap D)}{P( D)}\frac{P(B \cap C \cap D)}{P(B \cap D)}=P(B\mid D)\,P(C \mid  B \cap D)$

Answer (score 1):

You're fairly close.

Let's assume for simplicity that $P(A_1 \cap ... \cap A_n) > 0$. That way, all our conditional probabilities are well-defined.

We see that $P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P((A \cap B) \cap B)}{P(B)} = P(A \cap B \mid B)$ for all events $A, B$.

In particular, this means that $P(A_m | A_1 \cap ... \cap A_{m - 1}) = P(A_m \cap (A_1 \cap ... \cap A_{m - 1}) \mid A_1 \cap ... \cap A_{m - 1}) = P(A_1 \cap ... \cap A_m \mid A_1 \cap ... \cap A_{m - 1})$ for all $m \leq n$.

Thus, we see that $P(A_1) \cdot P(A_2 \mid A_1) \cdot ... \cdot P(A_n \mid A_1 \cap ... \cap A_{n - 1}) = P(A_1) \cdot \frac{P(A_1 \cap A_2)}{P(A_1)} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{P(A_1 \cap ... \cap A_n)}{P(A_1 \cap ... \cap A_{n - 1})} = P(A_1 \cap ... \cap A_n)$.

Formally, to get the last bit, we'd need to do an induction on $n$.